# CASE SENSITIVE Custom Validtion syntax for the IN operator for a column of SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, column, validation

I am entering the below condition as the validation formula for an attribute in the SP list, but it allows me to enter "innovation" instead of "Innovation", how can I avoid this.

```
 =OR([Asset type]="Innovation",[Asset type]="Communication")
```

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of Asset type column? Do you want your users to enter only Innovation or Communication in Asset type then you should consider creating choice column for this.

Comment: Because I have created the flow and  I do not want to change them, so is there any way to make it case-sensitive without changing the type? the type is "single line of text" and unfortunately also it is a title, so I cannot make it a dropdwnlist, unless I can move the properties of a title to another column (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280467/change-title-column-in-sharepoint-online), btw thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same formula in list validation settings.

1. Go to List settings
2. Click on Validation Settings
3. Enter your formula and Save.

If this formula is not working then try using this:

```
=IF(OR([Asset type]="Innovation",[Asset type]="Communication"), true, false)
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Comment: This does not work, I have added more screenshots, even if I remove the formula validation in the edit column section and rely only on the validation settings, still allows me to enter innovation –

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitive validation can be done easily with the `EXACT()` operator.

i.e:

```
=OR(EXACT([Asset type],"Innovation"),EXACT([Asset type],"Communication"))
```