# Editing Format of an attribute in SharePoint list is different from its viewwing format

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, column-formatting

I am working on a list and the format of a column is currency and currency format is $NZ and it shows the values as it's supposed to (e.g. $123,000), but when a user wants to enter a new row or edit an item this formatting disperse especially when a user wants to enter a different value, Moreover, it shows a Euro icon thing next to $. Is there any way to fix these

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you selected the correct currency format in column settings? Have you customized your list form?

Comment: I guess so @GaneshSanap, added a new screenshot, how Can I customize my list, can u plz elaborate more

Comment: I tried creating a currency column in NZ format and it is showing the same for me as well. And you can customize your list forms using Power Apps very easily.

Comment: It is cool, I am kind of new to SP, so I will learn how to work with Power App too soon, thx for pointing it out, it seems customize by Power App only appears in some of my lists and these list have a flow in msflow, right? so customize form by power app only appears in the lists which has a flow in MSflow?

Comment: Can u help me with this one too plz if u have some times https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/282805/case-sensitive-custom-validtion-syntax-for-the-in-operator-for-a-column-of-share

Comment: You will have a customize list forms with power apps option where you have higher permissions on list like edit/design or full control.

Comment: I am the owner, so it must show the customize form there too. I think I know why it does not show!, I created this individual list from Excel App while the other were created from a list manually. I guess that is the reason why this one does not have this option.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that a user can use commas and the SP correct it automatically. For example if a user enter 12,23 then it will be corrected to 1,223 and no error will be thrown out. No solution for that strange euro sign thing yet!